# How to make ExoPlayer compatible with all type video aspect ratios?

Tags: android, exoplayer, aspect-ratio, exoplayer2.x

I am using ExoPlayer for playing videos in my project. The problem is whatever video I tried to play the video resolution is always in  4:3 ratio only. I tried with the following code to overcome my problem. After adding the following lines the video seems to be completely stretched.

```
mExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
    exoPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

Comment: i am using ExoPlayer r2.5.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is:

```
simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
```

This code fit's the video to the view size but maintains it's aspect ratio by cropping from the sides.

Comment: compile time error under AspectRastioFrameLayout RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM is not found

Comment: use r2.5.4 version u got it there

Comment: this thing is working fine but the video became zoomed and became blurred